# MobileFirst linked resources

Tags: eclipse, ibm-mobilefirst

I want to share javascript and css files between my MobileFirst projects. Eclipse has the concept of a "Linked Folder", I am able to have two folders in two projects, but only one folder in source control. This way I can share common styles between projects. However the MobileFirst build ignores linked folders. If I have a linked folder under apps/common, when MobileFirst generates the project for the targeted environment, the linked folder contents are not copied across.

Is there a solution for this? Maybe a workaround so I can get some sources out of my solution and store them elsewhere .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the MobileFirst Studio plug-in for Eclipse does not support Linked Folders.

You may opt to suggest feature requests for future consideration by the product team, here: https://developer.ibm.com/mobilefirstplatform/help

Comment: Our main problem is that we have a main project which contains our app. We want to create child projects of this project. Each child project has its own branding of the app and also some additional features. They all have the same base code which we want to share.
Is there another solution how we can setup this case?

Comment: You could perhaps write Ant scripts to replace files in the resulting native project.

Comment: Thanks for your input Idan Adar. Our solution is to setup our git repository to use subtrees. Now the folder common is in a seperate git repository, which we can merge to the different apps.